# There is a student in this class who has been in every room of at least one building on campus

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

I am stuck on a question in Kenneth H. Rosen's *Discrete Mathematics* (7th edition):

> There is a student in this class who has been in every room of at least one building on campus.

My solution is

$$\exists x \forall y \exists z B(x,y,z),$$

where $B(x,y,z)$ means "student $x$ is in room $y$ in building $z$", and the universe of discourse

- $x$: {all students in the class},
- $y$: {all rooms},
- $z$:{all buildings}.

Comment: Post your question directly not in a link.

Comment: What does "room y in building z" mean? Presumably each building has various rooms in it, and your phrasing does not specify that the room y happens to be in building z.

Comment: i am rookie to math stackoverflow and i didn't know how to use mathjax thats why i put the answer in link
sorry for that

Comment: @ryang thank you very much for telling how to use mathjax so from your help i write the solution in maths using tex commands so thank you again

Comment: @coffeemath thank you i understand what i do wrong i am not specifying that "room y happens to be in building z".

Comment: For some student $s$ in this class, for some campus building $b,$ for each room $r,$ if $r$ is in $b,$ then $s$ has been in $r:$ $$∃s{\in}C \;∃b{\in}B \;∀r{\in}R \;\Big(P(r,b) \to \;Q(s,r)\Big)$$ (similar answer to Sundar's).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define:

$P(z,y)$ is ''z is in y"

$ Q(x,z)$ is "x has been in z"

$x$ ranges over
students in this class

$y$ ranges over buildings.

$z$ ranges over rooms on campus

Statement:

There is a student in this class who has been in every
room of at least one building on campus.

Using nested quantifiers, we can write it as:

$$
\exists x \ \exists y \ \forall z \ [ P(z, y) \rightarrow Q(x, z) ]
$$

Comment: can my answer that i think is wrong or correct please check atleast one time .

Comment: this is my answer so can you check my thinking is wrong or correct ?
∃x∀y∃zB(x,y,z)
x:all students
y:all rooms 
z:all buildings

Comment: Thanks for answer i got it

Comment: @ryang Thanks for Advice, I got it.